# How to add the category with search bar in magento2?

Tags: magento2, category, design

How to add the categories drop down with title "All categories" attached with the search bar seen in the image attached here with in Magento2 ?
[image]

I just need to show the search bar with "All Categories" list.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ravibhoraniya/3f6a8ebbcdd7647f23b6a49bdeec7df1